# WCF message:How to remove the SOAP Header element?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, wcf-binding

I try to delete the whole SOAP header from a WCF message, just only want to leave the envelope body. Anybody can give me an idea how can do that?

Create a WCF message like this:

```
**string response = "Hello World!";
Message msg = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "*", new TextBodyWriter(response));
msg.Headers.Clear();**
```

The sending SOAP message will be:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <Binary>Hello World!</Binary>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But I don't want to the SOAP header element, which I just only need the envelop body.How to remove the header element from a WCF message?

Comment: Can you just create the SOAP message yourself without using Message.CreateMessage(), using a StringBuilder or XmlSerializer?  That way you can build the string however you want, and send it using a WebClient.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the header?

Comment: Hi  Mangist,The WCF message is abstract class, it could not instance.the only way to create is call the CreateMessage function

Comment: Hi John.An SOAP message contain SOAP header is make more sence. but in order to compatible some other 3rd projects. the 3rd system which is an old system.

Comment: I had same problem, found out that SOAP headers were added by enabled WCF tracing and running under debugger.

Answer (score 7):

Option 1: Use bacicHttpBinding, it will not add content to the header (when not configured for security)

Option 2: Implement a custom mesaage encoder and strip the header there. anywhere before that there is a chance wcf will add the header back. See [sample encoder here](https://gist.github.com/yaronn/8653708).

Answer (score 5):

That question is a tricky one: let's take it step by step

### Some Context

The `Message` class writes its headers in its `ToString()` method. `ToString()` then calls an internal overload `ToString(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)` which then starts writing:

```
// System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message
internal void ToString(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
{
    if (this.IsDisposed)
    {
        throw TraceUtility.ThrowHelperError(this.CreateMessageDisposedException(), this);
    }
    if (this.Version.Envelope != EnvelopeVersion.None)
    {
        this.WriteStartEnvelope(writer);
        this.WriteStartHeaders(writer);
        MessageHeaders headers = this.Headers;
        for (int i = 0; i < headers.Count; i++)
        {
            headers.WriteHeader(i, writer);
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        MessageDictionary arg_60_0 = XD.MessageDictionary;
        this.WriteStartBody(writer);
    }
    this.BodyToString(writer);
    if (this.Version.Envelope != EnvelopeVersion.None)
    {
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

The `this.WriteStartHeaders(writer);` code writes the header tag regardless of the number of headers. It is matched by the `writer.WriteEndElement()` after the for loop. This `writer.WriteEndElement()` **must** be matched with the header tag being written, else the Xml document will be invalid.

So there is no way we can override a virtual method to get rid of the headers: `WriteStartHeaders` calls the virtual method `OnWriteStartHeaders` but the tag closing prevents simply shutting it off). We have to change the whole `ToString()` method in order to remove any header-related structure, to arrive at:

```
- write start of envelope
- write start of body
- write body
- write end of body
- write end of envelope
```

### Solutions

In the above pseudocode, we have control on everything but the "write body" part. All methods called in the initial `ToString(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)` are public except `BodyToString`. So we will need to call it through reflection or whichever method fits your needs. Writing a message without its headers simply becomes:

```
private void ProcessMessage(Message msg, XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
{
    msg.WriteStartEnvelope(writer); // start of envelope
    msg.WriteStartBody(writer); // start of body

    var bodyToStringMethod = msg.GetType()
        .GetMethod("BodyToString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    bodyToStringMethod.Invoke(msg, new object[] {writer}); // write body

    writer.WriteEndElement(); // write end of body
    writer.WriteEndElement(); // write end of envelope
}
```

Now we have a way to get our message content without the headers. But how should this method be invoked?

**We only want the message without headers as a string**

Great, we don't need to care about overriding the `ToString()` method that then calls the initial writing of the message. Just create a method in your program that takes a `Message` and an `XmlDictionaryWriter` and call it to get the message without its headers.

**We want the `ToString()` method to return the message without headers**

This one is a bit more complicated. We cannot easily inherit from the `Message` class because we would need to pull out *a lot* of dependencies out of the System.ServiceModel assembly. I won't go there in this answer.

What we can do is use the capabilities of some frameworks to create a [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) around an existing object and to intercept some calls to the original object in order to replace/enhance its behavior: I'm used to [Castle Dynamic proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/castle-dynamicproxy) so let's use that.

We want to intercept the ToString() method so we create a proxy around the `Message` object we are using and add an interceptor to replace the `ToString` method of the `Message` with our implementation:

```
var msg = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "*");
msg.Headers.Clear();

var proxyGenerator = new Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator();
var proxiedMessage = proxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyWithTarget(msg, new ProxyGenerationOptions(),
    new ToStringInterceptor());
```

The `ToStringInterceptor` needs to do almost the same thing as the initial `ToString()` method, we will however use our ProcessMessage method defined above:

```
public class ToStringInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (invocation.Method.Name != "ToString")
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        else
        {
            var result = string.Empty;
            var msg = invocation.InvocationTarget as Message;

            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            XmlDictionaryWriter xmlDictionaryWriter =
                XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateDictionaryWriter(new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter));

            try
            {
                ProcessMessage(msg, xmlDictionaryWriter);
                xmlDictionaryWriter.Flush();
                result = stringWriter.ToString();
            }
            catch (XmlException ex)
            {
                result = "ErrorMessage";
            }
            invocation.ReturnValue = result;
        }
    }

    private void ProcessMessage(Message msg, XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
    {
        // same method as above
    }
}
```

And here we are: calls to the ToString() method of the message will now return a envelope without headers. We can pass the message to other parts of the framework and know it should mostly work: direct calls to some of the internal plumbing of Message can still produce the initial output but short of a full reimplementation we cannot control that.

### Points of note

- This is the shortest way to removing the headers I found. The fact that the header serialisation in the writer was not handled in one virtual function only was a big problem. The code doesn't give you much wriggle room.
- This implementation doesn't use the same `XmlWriter` as the one used in the original implementation of `ToString()` in the `Message`, `EncodingFallbackAwareXmlTextWriter`. This class is internal in System.ServiceModel and pulling it out is left as an exercice to the reader. As a result, the output differs slightly since the xml is not formatted with the simple `XmlTextWriter` I use.
- The interceptor could simply have parsed the xml returned from the initial `ToString()` call and removed the headers node before letting the value bubble up. This is another viable solution.

### Raw code

```
public class ToStringInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (invocation.Method.Name != "ToString")
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        else
        {
            var result = string.Empty;
            var msg = invocation.InvocationTarget as Message;

            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            XmlDictionaryWriter xmlDictionaryWriter =
                XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateDictionaryWriter(new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter));

            try
            {
                ProcessMessage(msg, xmlDictionaryWriter);
                xmlDictionaryWriter.Flush();
                result = stringWriter.ToString();
            }
            catch (XmlException ex)
            {
                result = "ErrorMessage";
            }
            invocation.ReturnValue = result;
        }
    }

    private void ProcessMessage(Message msg, XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
    {
        msg.WriteStartEnvelope(writer);
        msg.WriteStartBody(writer);

        var bodyToStringMethod = msg.GetType()
            .GetMethod("BodyToString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        bodyToStringMethod.Invoke(msg, new object[] { writer });

        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var msg = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "*");
        msg.Headers.Clear();

        var proxyGenerator = new Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator();
        var proxiedMessage = proxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyWithTarget(msg, new ProxyGenerationOptions(),
            new ToStringInterceptor());

        var initialResult = msg.ToString();
        var proxiedResult = proxiedMessage.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine("Initial result");
        Console.WriteLine(initialResult);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Proxied result");
        Console.WriteLine(proxiedResult);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did not have your XmlBodyWriter but you could use data contract serializer or your xml body writer
But the trick is to use msg.WriteBody. this will omit the headers

```
var response = "Hello";            
Message msg = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "*",response, new DataContractSerializer(response.GetType()));
msg.Headers.Clear();
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb));
msg.WriteBody(xmlWriter);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Should be something like this:**

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(myXmlString); // suppose that myXmlString contains "<Body>...</Body>"

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Envelope/Body");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  string binary1 = xn["Binary1"].InnerText;
  string binary2 = xn["Binary2"].InnerText;
  Console.WriteLine("Binary: {0} {1}", binary1 , binary2);
}
```